# Ubuntu unable to find an executable, though which/whereis works

Tags: linux, bash, path

I updated Ubuntu from 15 to 16 (clean install). Mounted the old /home which was in a HDD and started installing the programs I need. I built and installed tmux2.3. The default installation script left the executable in /usr/local/bin.
When I call `tmux`, the error message I get is

```
bash: /usr/bin/tmux: No such file or directory
```

But `which` and `whereis` output

```
/usr/local/bin/tmux
tmux: /usr/local/bin/tmux
```

respectively.
`echo $PATH` gives

```
/home/elan/programs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin:/home/elan/scripts/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

It is from my old installation. It has `/usr/local/bin/` occurring before `/usr/bin`. So it is intriguing that the shell is unable to call `tmux`. I assume some non existent paths in `PATH` doesn't block the search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just forget all remembered locations:

```
hash -r
```

or check your aliases for `tmux`

```
alias
```

Comment: I restarted in the meanwhile, and it worked. I guess it redid the hashing. Was used to the usual immediate effect of change in PATH contents of Linux.

Comment: It remembers that `tmux` used to be in `/usr/bin` and stops there, even after you have moved it elsewhere. Restarting is a brutal way to cause the hashing to be reinitialized but it worked, of course